# Can we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} na_n=1\implies a_n={1\over n}+ {a\over n}$, where 0<|a|<1/2?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Can we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} na_n=1\implies a_n={1\over n}+ {a\over n}$, where 0<|a|<1/2 ??

**Thoughts**- This is because
$\lim_{n\to\infty} na_n=1\implies |na_n-1|<{\epsilon}$
choosing ${\epsilon}={1\over 2}$ for all n≥N and thus we can write
${1\over n}-{1\over 2n}<a_n<{1\over n}+{1\over 2n}\implies$ $a_n={1\over n}+ {a\over n}$ for all n≥N, 0<|a|<1/2 further is it possible from that ${\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_1^n a_n}={\infty}$ I think I'm making mistakes somewhere isn't it? Help needs

Comment: Yes I had that bit of sense making mistake but ..... BTW thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prove it, since it is false. If, say, $a_n=\frac{n+1}{n^2}$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}na_n=1$, but there is no $a$ such that $(\forall n\in\Bbb N):a_n=\frac1n+\frac an$.

Answer (score 0):

Already with $a_n=1/n$, this is not true since you ask $|a|>0$.

More generally, there is no reason this is true : $\left(a_n=\frac{\alpha_m n^m+...+\alpha_0}{\beta_{m+1} n^{m+1}+...+\beta_0}\right)_n$ with $\beta_{m+1}=\alpha_m\neq 0$ for example.